# Using find, xargs, etc. to output similarly named files

Tags: shell, find, xargs, command-line-arguments, pandoc

I have a folder full of HTML files:

```
001.htm
002.htm
003.htm
…
```

I want to run Pandoc on them to convert them to similarly named Markdown files:

```
001.md
002.md
003.md
```

This command works on one of them:

```
pandoc -f html -t markdown 001.htm -o 001.md
```

And I want to use `find` and `xargs` to automatically run a similar command on every file in the folder.

I got as far as this:

```
find *.htm | xargs -I {} -n 1 pandoc -f html -t markdown -o {}
```

…which truncates every file in the directory, so now I'm asking before I *really* break something.

What is wrong with my command above, and/or what's a completely different / more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to do that with this 1 liner. If you are flexible about the `xargs` and `find` part.

```
for f in ./*.htm; do pandoc -f html -t markdown "$f" -o "${f%.htm}.md"; done
```

If you want to act recursively (so: all `.htm` files in the current directory, and all subdirectories), then (assuming bash 4+) you can use the `globstar` shell option:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*.htm; do pandoc -f html -t markdown "$f" -o "${f%.htm}.md"; done
```

Comment: +1. xargs doesn't allow you the same flexibility of filename modification. Do **not** replace `*.htm` with `$(find...)` -- filenames with spaces will be properly handled  in the first case but *not* the second.

Comment: @glennjackman Unless you set the bash `$IFS` to `$'\n'` for that code section, in which case spaces aren't a problem -- newlines still are though.

Comment: Wow, there are two or three new things about the command line for me to learn from that snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using `{}` isn't flexible enough for some situations. This appears to be one of those.

A possible workaround would be to `-exec`a script from `find`, like so:

```
find . -name '*.htm' -exec ./convert-to-md.sh {} \;
```

The script file should look similar to this, depending on the exact `pandoc` command line:

```
#!/bin/bash
pandoc -f html -t markdown -o "${1/.htm/.md}" "${1}"
```

---

If you don't want to create and save a script file for this, you can always inline the `bash`script code:

```
find . -name '*.htm' | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'pandoc -f html -t markdown -o "${1/.htm/.md}" "${1}"' -
```

The additional `-`at the end serves to fill `$0`in bash, which usually includes the name of the shell script, positional arguments starting at `$0`.

This allows you to keep using `find`(even with `-print0`and `xargs -0` if you're handling weird file names), but doesn't require creation of a separate file.

Comment: Doesn't `find` handle weird file names on its own anyway? IIRC there's never a good reason to use `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …`

Comment: @slhck Newlines are valid file name components. The following demonstrates how this causes scripts to fail: `touch "$( echo -e 'foo\nbar' )" ; find . -name 'foo*bar' | xargs -n 1 echo File:`

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing a `{}` in the pandoc command

```
find . -name \*.htm | xargs -I {} -n 1 pandoc -f html -t markdown {} -o {}.md
```

But then you'll have files named `001.htm.md` -- you'll have to decide if this is a problem.